# Does a South African citizen with a UK visa need a transit visa for Amsterdam?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas, south-african-citizens, ams

I am taking my son to the U.K he has a South African passport so therefore has a visa for the UK. We are flying via Amsterdam, does he need a separate visa for Amsterdam ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=NL&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of onward tickets transiting by the same or first connecting aircraft.

So if the trip is in a single booking, he does **not** need a visa